# Interpolation of missing temperature data in Python

Tags: python, interpolation

I have monthly temperature data from several stations in eastern siberia. However, the one station which is necessary for my work is missing a lot of data, while other stations in the vicinity have good coverage. Is there a way to interpolate missing data based on the behavior of another dataset? Can't provide any code, since I don't know where to start and the datasets look like this:

[image]

The red dots is the data from the station with missing values while the green graph is from a station with good coverage

I would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction

Comment: I think you mean imputing or extrapolation instead of interpolation. Can you post a sample of dataset. Also how does other stations correlates with the station of interest? Do you have any past data of this station we can learn from?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is mathematical and not a programming problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are methods to do this, for instance, apply a FFT on the dataset with good coverage and see how well it fits your dataset with poor coverage while removing high-frequency terms.

However, I highly doubt that this will be any useful: your dataset with high coverage fits almost perfectly your dataset with poor coverage. Whatever is the method you want to apply, the best function that resembles your dataset with high coverage while fitting your dataset with poor coverage, is the dataset with high coverage itself.

Answer (score 0):

Let's create a trial dataset to work on your problem:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0, 30*2*np.pi, 30*24*2)
td = pd.date_range("2020-01-01", freq='30T', periods=t.size)

T0 = np.sin(t)*8 - 15 + np.random.randn(t.size)*0.2
T1 = np.sin(t)*7 - 13 + np.random.randn(t.size)*0.1
T2 = np.sin(t)*9 - 10 + np.random.randn(t.size)*0.3
T3 = np.sin(t)*8.5 - 11 + np.random.randn(t.size)*0.5
T = np.vstack([T0, T1, T2, T3]).T

features = pd.DataFrame(T, columns=["s1", "s2", "s3", "s4"], index=td)
```

It looks like:

```
axe = features[:"2020-01-04"].plot()
axe.legend()
axe.grid()
```

[image]

Then if your time series linearly correlates well, you can simply predict missing values by the mean of Ordinary Least Square regression. SciKit-Learn provides a convenient interface to perform this kind of computations:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Remove target site from features:
target = features.pop("s4")

# Split dataset into train (actual data) and test (missing temperatures):
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, target, train_size=0.25, random_state=123)

# Create a Linear Regressor and train it:
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(x_train, y_train)

# Assess regression score with test data:
reg.score(x_test, y_test) # 0.9926150729585087

# Predict missing values:
ypred = reg.predict(x_test)
ypred = pd.DataFrame(ypred, index=x_test.index, columns=["s4p"])
```

The result looks like:

```
axe = features[:"2020-01-04"].plot()
target[:"2020-01-04"].plot(ax=axe)
ypred[:"2020-01-04"].plot(ax=axe, linestyle='None', marker='.')
axe.legend()
axe.grid()
```

[image]

```
error = (y_test - ypred.squeeze())
axe = error.plot()
axe.legend(["Prediction Error"])
axe.grid()
```

[image]